Are there known super-exponential problems?
Can you point a particular problem, all algorithms solving which are of a super-exponential time-complexity?
I know that super-exponential problems exist, but is this a theorem of existence, or can a particular example be pointed?

I can't find a proof of this right now, but one commonly studied example would be cut elimination.
There is an effective method for cut-elimination in the sequent calculus, but the resulting proof can be super-exponential in size relative to the original (in the $\mathcal{O}(2^{2^n})$ sense I believe).

The problem of inferring and displaying the type of a term in the Hindley-Milner system is $Ω(2^{2^n})$. This is because there are certain sequences that cause types that are that large, so it takes that long just to display them.
A standard example is as follows. First define function composition:
(.) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
f . g = \x -> f (g x)

We also need pairing as a starting point:
pair : a -> a × a
pair x = (x , x)

Now, start writing the sequence:
f1 = pair . pair
f2 = f1 . f1
f3 = f2 . f2
...

The type of f1 is:
f1 : a -> (a × a) × (a × a)

Each of these has a type like a -> T(n, a), obtained by the recurrence:
T(0, a) = a × a
T(n+1, a) = T(n, T(n, a))

Where T(0, a) is the result of pair. Each step replaces each a in the prior expression with the entire prior expression. If we count the number of as, we get:
A(0, a) = 2
A(1, a) = 4
A(2, a) = 16
A(3, a) = 256
...
A(n+1, a) = A(n, a)²

So, the number of as we have to print in the result is $2^{2^n}$. The number of $×$ symbols is $2^{2^n}-1$ and the number of parentheses seems to be $2^{1 + 2^n} - 4$, assuming we parenthesize similarly to the scheme in the type I wrote for f1. But, writing the next f only takes a constant (or, realistically speaking, logarithmic) amount of text.
Nevertheless, this type system is used in practice, because people just don't write these sorts of degenerate programs. As far as I'm aware, the time/space usage of algorithms for inference and checking are proportional to the size of the types involved, and people don't actually write things that rely explicitly on these huge types.
Note: you can construct similar examples in logic with cut, as mentioned in the comments. Cut is analogous to composition, and eliminating cut can cause the same sort of blowup in proof size. This is analogous to writing out the normal form of what fn actually does, which copies x as many times in the term as a is copied in the type. You can probably create examples where just the terms/proofs grow, as well, not the types/propositions they inhabit/prove.
Also, I think this is only a lower bound. You can do even worse by making the terms slightly longer:
f0 x = (x, x, x)
f1 = f0 . f0 . f0
f2 = f1 . f1 . f1

I believe this grows like $3^{3^n}$. Generally, your first step sets the base, and the length of the other steps set the base of the exponent.

I asked about a problem that is a boolean function, not about an arbitrary function.
